# Invalid hook call error when showing/hiding component with React Redux

Tags: reactjs

I'm attempting to create a React/Redux component that shows/hides an element when clicked.

I'm using this to trigger the function from another component:

```
import React from 'react'
//Some other code...
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import onShowHelpClicked from '../help/AddHelpSelector'
<button onClick={onShowHelpClicked}>Help</button>
```

This this is AddHelpSelector:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { helpVisible } from './HelpSlice'

export const AddHelp = () => {
  const [isVisible, showHelp] = useState('')

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const onShowHelpClicked = () => {
    dispatch(
      helpVisible({
        isVisible,
      })
    )
    if (isVisible) {
      showHelp(false)
    } else {
      showHelp(true)
    }
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <h2 style={{ visibility: { isVisible } }}>Help section</h2>
    </section>
  )
}

export default AddHelp
```

Finally, this is HelpSlice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = [{ isVisible: false }]

const helpSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'help',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    helpVisible(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload)
    },
  },
})

export const { helpVisible } = helpSlice.actions

export default helpSlice.reducer
```

I'm fairly certain I'm doing multiple things wrong, as this is my first attempt to do anything with Redux and I'm still struggling to wrap my mind around it after a week of learning.

But specifically, when clicking the help button I get this error.

"Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app"

The linked documentation provides a way to test a component to see if React is importing properly, and it's not. But I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

I think it may be that I'm importing React multiple times, but if I don't then I can't use "useState."

What's the correct way to do this? I'm open to corrections on both my code as well as naming conventions. I'm using boilerplate code as a template as I try to understand this better after getting through the documentation as well as Mosh's 6 hour course which I just finished.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the `< AddHelpSelector />` component here `import onShowHelpClicked from '../help/AddHelpSelector'`, and then you try to use it as a callback handler for the button's `onClick`, which doesn't really make sense. I assume you actually wanted to only import the `onShowHelpClicked` function declared inside the `< AddHelpSelector />` component (which is not really a valid way of doing it). Since you want to control the visibility using redux state, you could just grab the flag from the redux store inside the `< AddHelpSelector />` component using `useSelector` hook. To set it, you're gonna do that in the component where your button is. For that, you just need to dispatch an action(like you already did), with the updated flag. No need for the local `useState`. Also, using the flag you could just conditionally render the element.

```
const App = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { isVisible } = useSelector((state) => ({ isVisible: state.isVisible }));
    const handleClick = () => {
         dispatch(
             helpVisible({
                 !isVisible,
             })
         )
    }

    return (<button onClick={handleClick}>Help</button>);
}
```

```
export const AddHelp = () => {
  const { isVisible } = useSelector((state) => ({ isVisible: state.isVisible }));

  return (
    <section>
      {isVisible && <h2>Help section</h2>}
    </section>
  )
}

export default AddHelp
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still having issues, I made a gist to show what I'm doing now. I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/TheNomadicAspie/92fc9bd7165eab12db4060529e38403b

Comment: Actually reading my code I realize it still doesn't make any sense. Sorry, I'm trying to understand what you want me to do with the example code you mentioned, but I'm just not getting it.

Comment: Looking at the gist, it looks almost right. The only thing that you are doing wrong is in the `OfferHelp` component. `onShowHelpClicked ` function declared there is not meant to be exported (it probably isn't working anyway). Handlers/functions declared in functional components are meant to either be used for different event handlers in that component(your case here, handler for button click event), or be passed down to children components. To make use of that functionality, you can now just simply render the `OfferHelp` component, let's say in the `PostsList` component.